# Can A Python Program Open An Text File On The Web?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web, text, server

I am making a program, and was wondering if a .txt file can be hosted on the web and be accessed by the open() function. Does anyone know about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `open()`, but you could use the [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) library to do it.

```
import requests

url_to_txt_file = ""
print(requests.get(url_to_txt_file).text)
```

Alternatively, you could use [`urllib.request`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/urllib.request.html#module-urllib.request).

```
import urllib.request

url_to_txt_file = ""
print(urllib.request.urlopen(url_to_txt_file).read())
```

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate the help, and the fact that it is concise!

Answer (score 1):

[urllib2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.urlopen) can return a file-like object from a URL. Here is an example from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#examples):

```
>>> import urllib2
>>> f = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.python.org/')
>>> print f.read(100)
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<?xml-stylesheet href="./css/ht2html
```

There is even the option to build an 'opener' if you really must use the `open` method:

```
proxy_handler = urllib2.ProxyHandler({'http': 'http://www.example.com:3128/'})
proxy_auth_handler = urllib2.ProxyBasicAuthHandler()
proxy_auth_handler.add_password('realm', 'host', 'username', 'password')

opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy_handler, proxy_auth_handler)
# This time, rather than install the OpenerDirector, we use it directly:
opener.open('http://www.example.com/login.html')
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, but, it is far too high level for me, as I am simply a beginner learning python.